# Entity Framework DatabaseContext.cs : The database transaction is not always rolled back on errors Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

An action item from the security scan is to address the following error

> The database transaction is not always rolled back on errors entity framework in DatabaseContext.cs

1. Open database connection with try {} block
2. Begin database transaction with try {} block
3. No unfinished transaction before closing database
4. Ensure the transaction is rolled back in the catch { } block or finally { } block

This is my `DatabaseContext.cs`:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    ...
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(
                    p => p.ClrType == typeof(string) // Entity is a string
                && p.GetColumnType() == null // No column type is set
            ))
        {
            property.SetIsUnicode(false);
        }

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DatabaseContext).Assembly);

        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasData(new Person
        {
            ..
        });
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = "system"; // this.loggedInUserService.UserId;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = "system"; // this.loggedInUserService.UserId;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync()
    {
        if (this.currentTransaction != null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        this.currentTransaction = await this.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return this.currentTransaction;
    }

    public async Task CommitTransactionAsync(IDbContextTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (transaction == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transaction));
        }

        try
        {
            await this.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.currentTransaction != null)
            {
                this.currentTransaction.Dispose();
                this.currentTransaction = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            this.currentTransaction?.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.currentTransaction != null)
            {
                this.currentTransaction.Dispose();
                this.currentTransaction = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should I use `try-catch` block in the `OnModelCreating` method in `DatabaseContext` to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The database transaction is not always rolled back on errors entity framework in DatabaseContext.cs

> Should I use try-catch block in the OnModelCreating

No.  Whatever rule is evaluating your code is probably confused by your transaction helper methods.  Probably I would just remove those, as they don't look very helpful.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're suggesting to ignore the warning, correct?

Comment: I don't know where the warning came from, but your OnModelCreating looks fine